# Python DateTime Index - Unable to Remove Dates - ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am unable to remove dates from my dataframe after the second datetime index filter. I get this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp`.

Creating the base dataset (just run this snippet first, should take about 45 seconds to create the dataframe):

```
#2016
url = "https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42040h2016.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/"
data_csv = urlopen(url)
df = pd.read_csv(data_csv, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)


############################################################
# Buoy 42040 Data Preparation
############################################################

#Remove useless variables
df.drop(['WDIR', 'WSPD', 'GST', 'WVHT', 'DPD', 'APD', 'MWD', 'PRES', 'VIS', 'TIDE', 'VIS'], 
        axis = 1, inplace = True)

#Reset Index
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

#remove 1st row contains erronous characters
df = df.iloc[1:]

#Rename Year column
df = df.rename(columns={'#YY': 'YY'})

#drop rows containing headers / strings 
df.iloc[24070:24080,:] #24077
df = df[df.MM.str.contains("mo") == False]

#Create date column then merge
df['Date'] = df[df.columns[0:3]].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)),axis=1)
df['Time'] = df[df.columns[3]].str.cat(df[df.columns[4]], sep=':')
df['Date.Time'] = df['Date'] + ':' + df['Time']

#Convert to numeric from objects 
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

#Convert Date and Date.Time to pd.datetime classes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
df['Date.Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date.Time'], format='%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M', utc=True)

#Convert dataframe index to a datetime index, then drop other times
df = df.set_index('Date.Time')
df.drop(['hh', 'mm', 'Time', 'Date'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
#Remove 2014 data
df = df[df['YY'] != 2014]
```

Check to see if datetime index works. Looks good.

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 111356 entries, 2015-01-01 00:50:00+00:00 to 2018-09-04 00:00:00+00:00
Data columns (total 6 columns):
YY      111356 non-null int64
MM      111356 non-null int64
DD      111356 non-null int64
ATMP    89208 non-null float64
WTMP    110737 non-null float64
DEWP    89221 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(3)
memory usage: 5.9 MB
```

Remove February and March 2016 data from the data frame because its bad. No problem here:

```
df = df.loc[(df.index <= '2016-01-31') | (df.index >= '2016-04-01')]
```

Remove December 2016 from the data frame because it is also bad, but then theres an issue:

```
df = df.loc[(df.index <= '2016-11-31') | (df.index >= '2017-01-01')]

ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
```

If there is an alternative method anyone would like to suggest this would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This code is quite messy, but it only goes up to `jul`. Try adding the rest of those up to `dec` in all places and see whether the problem goes away.

Comment: That was Jul 2018 data. I removed everything but 2016 data to focus on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put the first date as 31st November 2016, but November only has 30 days.  Change that line to `df = df.loc[(df.index <= '2016-11-30') | (df.index >= '2017-01-01')]` and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I looked at the data I was removing and it is the data that the filter errors out on. If I remove the command below, it doesn't hurt the rest of the code.

`df = df[df.MM.str.contains("mo") == False]`

Thank you for looking at this post!